# Charts on JSP page

Tags: jquery, jsp, charts

I want to create an interactive organizational/hierarchical chart. 
Please suggest an API supported on JSP/JQuery.
I want an interactive multidimensional chart such that i click on a component and its further details are revealed. something like implementing multi level abstraction

Answer (score 1):

Try `Google charts`. It supports building organizational charts through for a given json data. You can find the documentation at:-
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#Example

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of Libraries Available for charting

1. http://www.highcharts.com/
   Youcan find the demo here http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax/
2. http://www.chartjs.org/
   That is HTML5 Chart Module
3. http://www.amcharts.com/
   This is also JavaScript Chart Module demo - http://www.amcharts.com/demosh

And you can find some Interesting comparison here. You can get the Idea from that. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks

Thank you.